# Scheduling queries to run when sql server is not busy

Tags: sql-server, scheduled-tasks

Is it possible to schedule some queries not for specific times but to run when sql server is not busy?

Is there any way to calculate the business of the sql server?

Comment: You can schedule a job, then click `schedule`, then in the schedule type, you can choose `start whenever the CPU becomes idle`

Comment: I would refrain from trying to figure out when Sql Server is not busy because - right this second, it's not busy, but in 2 seconds there might be a huge amount of activity.  I think you'd be better off identifying a specific time when you 'know' there would be little activity.

Comment: For what its worth, I had to restart the SQL Agent to make the Idle Condition take effect and to disable it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes you can.

You can create a job with the query or procedure you want to run.

On **Schedule** you can set it to run **Whenever the CPU becomes idle**.

[image]

[Here you can find how to configure the CPUs idle limit.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189065.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

An Idle condition is defined at the SQL Agent properties, Advanced

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189065.aspx

The select it in the schedule type for the job as Rafael said in his comment